# Testing a PCL with F# FAKE

Tags: c#, mstest, portable-class-library, f#-fake

I have a solution with a PCL class library project and a test project testing the library (MSTest). The PCL uses `Microsoft.Net.Http` and `Microsoft.Bcl.Compression` to do some gzip downloading. Both the PCL and the test project reference both before-mentioned libs using Nuget.

When I run the test in Visual Studio, the tests work and pass. When I run the tests from F# FAKE

```
Target "MainTests" (fun _ ->
    !! (testDir + @"my-dll-name.dll") 
      |> MSTest (fun p -> p)
)
```

all the tests fail with

```
Test method XXX.AvailableLanguagesShoudlExist threw exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void     
System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression(System.Net.DecompressionMethods)'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is probably that your Mstest.exe is using a wrong F# or FSharp.Core.dll version - I assume we need more details to figure this out.

- please make sure Visual Studio build process and FAKE build process use the same version.
- maybe you need to use binding redirects

Comment: Can you give me more info? This is my first FAKE build script, with default settings according to samples and documentation

Comment: The problem is that this is not related to FAKE. We are only using a couple of command line calls to automate your build. The real problem is that the command line / mstest is using a different F# version than VS. If this is an open source project then I'd be happy to help. If not then maybe others could provide a list with common issues.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the problem on a simple project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/PCLTestProject.zip. On this, in VS tests are ok, using the fake build script they fail (not the same error, but may be related)